# Bias of a different estimator for linear regression slope

Tags: regression

We know he fitted estimator for $\beta_1$ is
$$
\hat{\beta_1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}}
$$

Now, given the following estimator:
$$
\beta_1' = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{y_i-\bar{y}}{x_i-\bar{x}}
$$

How can I find out its bias? How can I calculate its $MSE$? I'm not sure how to treat that random variable, what are its properties, etc.

Comment: As it stands there is no way this question can be answered, as a bias needs to be assessed relative to some process having generated the data, which you do not state. Is it $y_i=\alpha+\beta x_i+u_i$ where something is assumed about the relationship between $u_i$ and $x_i$?

Comment: Exactly, I'm assuming simple linear regression such that $\hat{y_i}=\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}x_i + e_i$. where $e_i$ is normally distributed.

Comment: The more interesting point than the distribution for $e$ is what you assume about (in)dependence between $x$ and $e$.

Answer (score 1):

That estimator is not biased.

\begin{eqnarray}
E[\beta_1^\prime] &=& \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n E \left[ \frac{y_i - \bar{y}}{x_i - \bar{x}}\right]\\
 &=& \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{E[y_i] - E[\bar{y}]}{x_i - \bar{x}} \\
 &=& \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\beta_1 x_i - \beta_1 \bar{x}}{x_i - \bar{x}}\\
 &=& \beta_1
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: There is a missing bar over x on the last denominator.

Comment: Why is the second equality true?

Comment: @galah92 because expectation is linear and the x's are fixed.

Comment: @AdamO But why the $x$'s are fixed..? And are you relying on the fact that $E[y_i] = \beta_1x_i + \beta_0$?